# Dnsmasq + DHCP: how to return empty DNS to all clients

Tags: linux, dns, wifi, dnsmasq

i've configured a Raspberry Pi3 as a Hotspot. All works well, but clients receive as DNS IP the same IP of the gateway. I need to send an Empty DNS, like this:

[image]

My dnsmasq.conf file is:

```
interface=wlan0      
bind-interfaces      
server=0.0.0.0
server=0.0.0.0
domain-needed       
bogus-priv           
dhcp-range=192.168.10.10,192.168.10.200,12h
dhcp-option=6,0.0.0.0
```

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Comment: @Danpe yes, using dhcp server. It's more configurable. Try to set empty DNS

Comment: Which DNS server did you use? and what were your `Dnsmasq.conf`? or you removed Dnsmasq completely ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you would want to disable DNS for your clients, but you could try to specify 127.0.0.1 (localhost) for DNS instead of 0.0.0.0.  That should have the same effect.

Comment: At the moment i receive as DNS the same IP of the gateway. I should change some other .conf file (after dnsmasq.conf?)

Comment: P.S. set to 127.0.0.1 is not the same to have an empty DNS. Maybe i should try with something else from DNSMasq?

Answer (score 0):

To make dnsmasq send no value for DNS, set option 6 to be empty (no comma, no IP address):

```
dhcp-option=6
```

It is detailed in [the example config file](http://thekelleys.org.uk/gitweb/?p=dnsmasq.git;a=blob;f=dnsmasq.conf.example;h=574b053285e8466e64db98d043227eaed9b44217;hb=94b6878821b59b32353525e1594efeffd109fa9d#l336) for option 3 (default route):

```
# Override the default route supplied by dnsmasq and send no default
# route at all. Note that this only works for the options sent by
# default (1, 3, 6, 12, 28) the same line will send a zero-length option
# for all other option numbers.
#dhcp-option=3
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put `port=0` in your dnsmasq config file and remove any `dhcp-option=6` lines.  dnsmasq will then not serve DNS at all and it won't send any DNS information to DHCP clients.